# Combinations: form 3 teams from 30 people

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can you form 3 teams from 30 people where each team consists of 1 team leader and 9 other members?

## Attempted solution

I need to pick 3 team leaders and the order is unimportant and there are no repetitions:

$C_{30}^3$=4060

For the first team I have 27 people to choose from and I need to pick 9. Order is not important and there are no repetitions:

$C_{27}^9$=4686825

For the second team I have 18 people left and I need to pick another 9:

$C_{18}^9$=48620

For the third team I have 9 people left:

$C_{9}^9$=1

To get the solution, I just multiply all results:

$4060*4686825*48620*1=925166131890000$

Is it correct?

Comment: The expression is correct, I have not done the numerical calculation. But the reasoning you used is very dangerous. If you were counting the number of divisions into **teams** (no leaders) then $\binom{30}{20}\binom{20}{10}$ would be wrong by a factor of $6$. That's because there really is no "first" team. My first answer has a slightly reworded version of your reasoning, same answer of course. I also give a second solution based on team counting, where the issues are I hope made clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $\dbinom{30}{3}$ ways of selecting the team leaders. Now line up the team leaders in order of height.

The tallest team leader can select her team in $\dbinom{27}{9}$ ways. For each of these ways, the next tallest team leader can select her team in $\dbinom{18}{9}$ ways. Multiply.

**Another way:** We will first select the teams. For each selection, the team leaders can be then chosen in $10^3$ ways.

To find the number of ways of selecting the teams, let us first **change** the 
problem to selecting three teams, to wear respectively blue, white, and red uniforms. The blue uniform people can be chosen in $\dbinom{30}{10}$ ways. For each of these ways, the white uniform people can be chosen in $\dbinom{20}{10}$ ways, and we are finished.

But for each way to select the **teams**, there are $3!$ ways to assign the uniforms. Thus the total number of ways to select naked teams with leaders is
$$\frac{1}{3!}\binom{30}{10}\binom{20}{10}10^3.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you have three teams at the beginning, and assign the 30 people into the groups:

First, choose the members of the three teams. So there should be $C_{30}^{10}\times C_{20}^{10}$ ways of doing that. Then, choose a leader for each team and there are  $10^3$ ways of doing this.

However, if you just want to separate the 30 people into 3 groups, your approach is correct, which is $\frac{1}{6}$ of the other case.